# Does the picture specs means it is an SSD disk?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, ata

I would like to know if the next picture means it is an SSD disk and if so why the model name which is **KINGSTONE SUV400S37240G ATA DEVICE** contains the word **ATA**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image itself does not tell if this is an SSD or not.

Searching for the type gives me this: Kingston SUV400S37/240G 240GB SATA SSD

So yes, it is an SSD.

ATA is the connector type and has nothing to do with it being an SSD or not.